# STM32L031 not running after stopping debugging

Tags: stm32, debugging, eclipse

I'm using a STM32L031 with Eclipse for my application. When in debug mode everything works fine. But when I stop debug mode or power off and on again, the STM32L031 stops working.

I had expected that after downloading the code into the chip, it should work whenever I power it on.

And since I'm not using an evaluation board, there is no reset button so I cannot reset it.

How to solve this problem? Or is there a way to reset the chip without requiring the Reset button hardware?

Comment: What is it doing when you 'stop debug mode'? I guess there are some breakpoints still in the code which didn't get cleaned up before you reset.

Comment: Have you wired the NRST pin in a way which could prevent normal startup? Do you use some sort of semi-hosting which might prevent normal running (because of hard coded breakpoints)? Is the debugger still connected when you do the power cycle?

Comment: If you probably have an SMT resistor on the NRST line, to which  you can solder a small wire to pull low for a test reset.  Or (at least if your supply is current limited) you can just touch something grounded (or via a low value resistor) to it.

Comment: You ought to be able to re-attach the debugger to a running target - this will help to investigate where it is stuck.

Comment: Supposing you HAVE a pullup resistor on the NRST line just short NRST to ground. If you don't - add a 10kOhm one. Also, how is your BOOT0 wired?

Comment: "I had expected that after downloading the code into the chip, it should work whenever I power it on" - this is only true if you upload the code into flash and program your MCU to boot from it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can stop it from running is if you are using semi-hosting.  In your project properties, try to remove the following two symbols:

[image]

I have multiple projects, and only some of them require the removal of semi-hosting.  I haven't yet figured out why it is necessary for some and not others...

Oh, and if powercycling the board doesn't work, then a reset button wouldn't, either.

Comment: Semihosting comes into play if you're using functions that use standard I/O, like `printf()`. If you don't call those functions, your application is no different with and without semihosting.

Comment: @duskwuff No experience with this controller in particular, but AFAIK "hosted application" in C means your code starts with `main`, as opposed to "unhosted" applications which start at something like `__program_start`. Incidentally, if you run unhosted, you have to initialize STDOUT yourself before you can use `printf`, but it may be not the only difference.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev True, but semihosting is a separate thing entirely. Enabling/disabling semihosting doesn't affect how applications start up.

Answer (score 1):

When using the debugger, the processor is forced to execute from a certain region.
On power-on reset, the bootloader determines where it should start. Some pins or flash location provide the bootloader with instructions.

[image: stm32l031 boot options]